# How to sort datable on style background

Tags: javascript, datatable

I would like to sort my datable on the style background . It is possible? How ?

```
<td class="sorting_1" style="background: red;"></td>
<td class="sorting_1" style="background: white;"></td>
```

EDIT : i add a attribute data-order and i would like to filter on it :

```html
  <td class="sorting_1" data-order="red" style="background: red;"></td>
   <td class="sorting_1" data-order="white" style="background: white;"></td>
```

My dataTable has 5 columns and i want to filter on the five : 
                            "aoColumns": [
                                {}, {}, {}, {}, {targets: 0, "data": { _: "0.display", sort: "0.@data-order", type: "0.@data-order" } }
                            ]

I have an error message.. Any Idea?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: What do you mean by sorting ? Do you mean organised by colors ? Blue background td next to blue background td and red background td next to red background td ?

Comment: When using https://datatables.net/ you can add data-order attribute and place the value you want to sort by. In this case, the background color: data-order="red" or data-order="white"...

Comment: more information -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806737/custom-sorting-of-jquery-datatable-columns

Comment: @daddygames  i added a attribute data-order and i would like to filter on it :

My dataTable has 5 columns and i want to filter on the five : "aoColumns": [ {}, {}, {}, {}, {targets: 0, "data": { _: "0.display", sort: "0.@data-order", type: "0.@data-order" } } ]

I have an error message.. Any Idea?