# Sorting strings values to table bottom in date type column in Datatable

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

I am using datatable and I have a date column which contains empty values. i have replace all empty values with 'Not yet attempted' string. The dates have to be ordered in descending; putting latest on top and 'Not yet attempted' at bottom. I have used [absoluteOrder](https://datatables.net/blog/2016-12-22)  . It has put 'Not yet attempted' to the bottom but the dates are now being sorted as string as opposed to date type. Please tell me how can I achieve desired functionality. TIA

```
var nonDate= $.fn.dataTable.absoluteOrder( [
        { value: 'Not yet attempted', position: 'bottom' }
    ] );

    $(document).ready(function () {
        dataTable = $("#candidate-table").DataTable({
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "columnDefs": [
            { targets: 3, type: nonDate },
            {
                type: 'natural-ci',
                targets: [0,2]
            }],
            "order": [[3, "desc"]]
        });
    });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldjCj.png)

Comment: This answer can help you: [Custom Sorting of jQuery dataTable Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806737/custom-sorting-of-jquery-datatable-columns)

Comment: this didnt help because i am populating data in the table using jquery fn dataTable.row.add(rowToAdd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution finally. We have to set the data-order in each  tag for both empty and non empty cells. For the date value, I converted the date to  [YYYYMMDDHHMMSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19448436/how-to-create-date-in-yyyymmddhhmmss-format-using-javascript/19448513) format and set it to data-order. Then the column was rendered adding "order": [[3, "desc"]], to the function.

```
dataTable = $("#candidate-table").DataTable({
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                type: 'natural-ci',
                targets: [0, 2]
            },
            {
                targets: 3,
                createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                    if (cellData == "Not yet attempted")
                        $(td).attr('data-order', 0)
                    else
                        $(td).attr('data-order', ((new Date(cellData)).toISOString().replace(/[^0-9]/g, "").slice(0, -3)))
                },
                render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    if (type === "sort") {
                        var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(meta.settings);
                        var td = api.cell({ row: meta.row, column: meta.col }).node();
                        data = $(td).attr('data-order');
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            }],
        "order": [[3, "desc"]],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'csv',
                text: 'Export',
                title: 'Candidates',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':not(:last-child)',
                    modifier: {
                        search: 'none'
                    }
                },
                className: 'btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-save-file csvbtn'
            }
        ],
    });
```